# How to test angularjs application with a nonangular login page in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I am struggling with finding a way to test my angularjs application that has a non-angular login page.

All of the app's pages are protected by a login, so whatever page I test, I will need to login first. 
I have looked through all kinds of ideas on the internet and nothing seems to work -  it just doesn't redirect me to the app after logging in with protractor, while all works great when I do it manually.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
onPrepare: function() {
            browser.driver.get('http://localhost:9000/app);
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName')).sendKeys('admin');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass123');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginBtn')).click();

            return browser.driver.wait(function() {
                return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                    return /home/.test(url);
                });
            }, 10000);
```

I have also tried with setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` but still got nowhere.

Does anybody know what else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ignoreSynchronization=true` before `browser.get()`, and reset to `false` after click login button.

```
onPrepare: function() {

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  browser.driver.get('http://localhost:9000/app);
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName')).sendKeys('admin');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass123');
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginBtn')).click();

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

  return browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          return /home/.test(url);
      });
  }, 10000);
```

if above code not fix your issue, try to move above code for login into a function and don't call the function in `onPrepare`, call the function like in `beforeAll`.  I had some fail experience start to interact with browser inside `onPrepare`